# Saving a video in Python with the MJPG codec to an AVI file

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am developing a Python application that captures images from the camera. I want to capture them at a resolution of 1920x1080 at 30fps (supported by the Logitech C920 camera).

The problem is that when I change the codec to AVI format, I can't play what I recorded using a program like VLC or Dragon Player.

```py
import cv2
import time

# Define the codec and create a VideoWriter object with H.264 codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30.0, (1920, 1080))

# Open the default camera (usually the first camera, index 4)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

# Check if the camera opened successfully
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open camera.")
    exit()

# Record for a maximum of 10 seconds
start_time = time.time()
while (time.time() - start_time) < 10:
    # Read a frame from the camera
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame.")
        break

    # Write the frame to the video file
    out.write(frame)

    # Display the frame (optional)
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

# Release the video writer and camera
out.release()
cap.release()

# Close all OpenCV windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have checked the drivers, and with the MJPG codec, it provides the following frame rate for a resolution of 1920x1080:

```
> v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext -d /dev/video0


...
    [2]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        ...
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.042s (24.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

**The problem is that when I change the codec to AVI format, I can't play what I recorded using a program like VLC or Dragon Player.**

The .avi file is like:

```
RIFF*\00\00AVI LIST\DC%\00\00hdrlavih8\00\00\005\82\00\00\00N\ED\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\80\00\008\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00LIST\84$\00\00strlstrh8\00\00\00vidsXVID\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FF\FF\FF\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\808strf(\00\00\00(\00\00\00\80\00\008\00\00\00\00XVID\00\EC^\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00...
\00LIST\00\00\00moviidx1\00\00\00\00
```

Comment: please present such a file for analysis

Comment: sorry, I've already added the content of the .avi file

Comment: the whole file please, not what you did there. that's not useful.